# How to check for the existence of a file?

Tags: android, android-file

```
String extra=imagepath.get(i).toString();
String extra2=imageid.get(i).toString();
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.webdata/files/Download/" + extra2 + ".jpg";
File f = new File(path);
if(f.exists())
{ 
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File already exists....",
    //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else
{
    downloadfile();
}
```

I am using the above code to check if a file exists or not. I have checked it with one file and it works fine, but when I use it in my application where there are multiple (100-200) images it always starts downloading files whether they exist or not. Is there a better method than this?

Comment: I think it should word. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: can't tell from the code you posted alone. Why do you store the path in a list `imagepath`, if you then construct it from the image id? Maybe you are checking for the wrong path (btw. hard-coding the path of the sd-card is bad practice, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for the root or `Context.getExternalCacheDir()` to ensure it works on all versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check how many images on folder:-

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] imageDirs = extStore.listFiles(filterForImageFolders);
```

after above you run the loop and check u r condition:-

```
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
     // ur condition
}
```